# Moving all emails directed to me and another distro from one specific person

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules

I am part of distribution email and I want to move all the emails from my manager being sent to me or the distribution email. Can this be done?

Comment: To answer you. Yes. However I doubt that is your real question. Can you edit your post, explain what you actually want to know and include the things you've tried to avoid us suggesting things that you know don't work

Comment: It can and is pretty basic using the rules features built in to Outlook. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

As music2myear mentioned above, Outlook rule could help achieve this. You can use Outlook rules to automatically forward/redirect all messages to another account.

Please check this official document:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-rules-to-automatically-forward-messages-45aa9664-4911-4f96-9663-ece42816d746